# Query in Oracle for running sum

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to pull the result set with sum of the previous record and current record.

**Logic**

My table is having one key column C1 and a numeric column C2. I need a result like below example. I need 3 columns as the out put out which 1 columns is with running sum. First two columns are same as source with the thrid columns but

- The first record of C3 = first record C2.
- Second record C3 = "First Record C2 + Second Record C2";
- Third record C3 = "First Record C2 + Second Record C2 + Thrid Record C2"

and it should continue for all the records.

**Ex.**
I have one source table like

```
C1     C2
---------
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

I Need output like below

```
C1   C2   C3
-------------
a    1    1
b    2    3
c    3    6
```

Comment: This is unclear.  Please format properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
select c1, c2, sum(c2) over (order by c2) c3
  from table_name
```